# I have an excel chart that displays the wrong value for 5 data points out of 1000

Tags: excel, charts

I have a chart in excel (line graph) that displays the values for 6/30 and 7/5 incorrectly. The data are all directly entered (no formulas) - stock price on those dates.

For 6/30 the chart shows 326.25
for 7/5 it shows 329.22

The data (excerpt) is below

```
6/9/17   $606.36 
6/12/17  $612.02 
6/13/17  $612.08 
6/14/17  $608.38 
6/15/17  $613.01 
6/16/17  $593.81 
6/19/17  $596.86 
6/20/17  $585.20 
6/21/17  $574.01 
6/22/17  $579.63 
6/23/17  $574.98 
6/26/17  $579.61 
6/27/17  $578.77 
6/28/17  $569.08 
6/29/17  $559.67 
6/30/17  $570.46 
7/3/17   $571.71 
7/4/17   $571.71 
7/5/17   $546.83 
7/6/17   $507.48 
7/7/17   $501.39 
7/10/17  $507.54 
7/11/17  $499.57 
7/12/17  $493.15 
7/13/17  $506.93 
7/14/17  $506.31 
7/17/17  $503.66 
7/18/17  $495.69 
7/19/17  $493.44 
7/20/17  $502.56 
7/21/17  $511.46 
7/24/17  $498.25 
7/25/17  $511.01 
7/26/17  $515.97 
7/27/17  $529.01 
7/28/17  $526.92 
7/31/17  $539.82 
8/1/17   $547.86 
8/2/17   $542.89 
8/3/17   $529.28 
8/4/17   $536.82 
8/7/17   $541.66 
8/8/17   $530.97
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Exactly - the DATA looks fine, but here is the chart  file:///C:/Users/badgleymb/Documents/EXCEL%20Chart.jpg  Not sure how to get the chart to you